# Batch job for creating a text file for movie files

Tags: command-line, scripts

I would like to preserve the movie name before renaming them. Can this be done for all files in a folder, at ones?

So from current movie name "A Clockwork Orange_(1971) Stanley Kubrick(DivX).avi", script will name a text file for "A Clockwork Orange_(1971) Stanley Kubrick(DivX)" and put the full name; "A Clockwork Orange_(1971) Stanley Kubrick(DivX).avi", in the new file...

Please explain step by step.

Comment: You mean you want to create a text file with the same file name as a movie file, and put the movie's file name as content in the text file? I don't think I fully understand what you want to achieve...

Comment: Something like `for f in *.avi; do echo "$f" > "${f%.avi}.txt"; done` you mean? or do you want all the names in a single file?

Comment: Looks good to me, one file per movie. Could I run the above in a terminal? just cd to the folder, and sudo the above line? If I have other file extension;  should I just change to .divx or ie .mp4? Thanks for your help!

Comment: I get an syntax error for "do"

Comment: @TerjeFolkvord Don't use `sudo` with steeldriver's command, because 1) the command doesn't require root, and 2) `sudo` can only run files; that's why you got a syntax error.

Comment: @TerjeFolkvord Yes, you can just change the file extension in the command, e.g. `for f in *.mp4; do echo "$f" > "${f%.mp4}.txt"; done`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Steeldriver done beat me to it, and more elegantly. I'm not gonna be in his class for a decade at least. But since I already wrote and tested this, I'll post it, FWIW. The following code is to be put in a script. Then you run the script in a terminal with the sole argument being the directory containing the files you want to deal with. If you wanted to run it from a gui file browser, you'd need to invoke it with something like `xterm -e /path/to/this_script.sh $f`, `f` being whatever variable the file browser passes on the /path/to/directory as.

So open a plain text file with an editor, something like geany, leafpad, or (shudder) gedit.

Copy the code below into it, starting with the "#!/bin/bash two lines below this.

##### Do NOT copy this line, start with the next line beginning "#!"

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

# repeats until you enter a valid directory
# you might add a test to make sure you have adequate permissions.
DIr="$1"
while [ ! -d "$DIr" ] || [ $DIr = / ]; do
      read -p "$DIr is not a valid argument. Enter a 
      directory other than '/' with files you want to process:" DIr
done

# canonicalizes directory name
DIr="$(readlink -f "$DIr")"

for FILE in $DIr/*; do
    BASENAMe="$(basename "$FILE")"
    BASE_NAME_minus_ext="$(echo -n "$BASENAMe" | rev | cut -d'.' -f2- | rev)"

    # If you want 'em all in a single list, instead use:
    # echo "$BASENAMe" >> "$DIr/List_of_names_minus_extensions"
    echo "$BASENAMe" > "$DIr"/"$BASE_NAME_minus_ext"

done
```

##### Do NOT copy this line. Copy through and including "done" just above. No more.

Save the file with a convenient name, like "list.sh", without the quote marks. Move it to one of the directories in your path. You can display the path with the command:

```
echo $PATH
```

That will return a string which is a bunch of directories seperated by colons ( the ":" character). The individual directory names all begin with a "/". They do NOT include the ":". Any of those directories will do. If it is in your path, I suppose the most conventional one would be:

/usr/local/bin

but it really doesn't matter as long as it is one of them. If you did that with a graphical file browser (like Nautilus, Thunar, or Pcmamfm), right click on the script (i.e. the file you just created and moved) and click "properties" and then "permissions" if that is a separate tab. Set it as executable by you. All sorts of ways to do that. Most convenient is to set as owned by your user name and the group of the same name and check executable, readable and writable by owner and group but none of those by other.

If you are doing this from command line:

```
chmod -v ug+r+w+x /usr/local/bin/list.sh
```

using whichever of the directories on the path you put the file in and whatever filename you gave it.

Or, if that fails, do these 2, one at a time, in order:

```
sudo chown your_user_name:your_user_name /usr/local/bin/list.sh
sudo chmod -v ug+r+w+x /usr/local/bin/list.sh
```

Now you should have an executable script that can be invoked by typing it's name into a terminal and pressing enter, either plain like this:

```
list.sh
```

or with the name of the directory you want it to act on like this:

```
list.sh /path/to/directory_that_has_your_movies
```

If you don't include the full /path/to/directory_you_want_acted_upon, it will make a reasonable guess about where to find it. It might guess wrong. If you want to save yourself keystrokes you can give the script a shorter name like "lis" or if you want to make it easier to remember what it does, you can give it a longer name like "list_files_within_without_extensions.sh. The ".sh" ending is a common convention for script names just so you will know what the file is by looking at its name. you can name it anything, even "George Humperdink, III" if you want to, but spaces and commas tend to cause trouble.

Some more thoughts:
In light of your response to sudodus, I must caution, do NOT use sudo to run either his command or my script. I can't think of any good reason for movies to be owned by root or in a directory owned by root. They absolutely should NOT be run in a viewer by root. We don't have much of a malware problem in the 'nix ecosystem, but invoking media players, even pic viewers, as root, is asking for trouble and if enough people ask for trouble, someone will provide it. Therefore the files MUST be readable by a plain user, and it would be darned awkward to keep them in a directory that wasn't readable, writable, and "executable" by a plain user. If either his command or my script fails in a way that sudo would have prevented, then you need to change the perms of the files or the directory they are in. Using sudo would be like setting fire to the furniture because the AC has made the room too cold. It will just give you MORE permission problems by creating root owned list files. Never use sudo unless you HAVE to, and then only if it makes sense. If it doesn't make sense to have to use sudo, then fix the problem, don't work around it.

Also, yes his command will work for other extensions if you make the logical changes in it. The script works for any extensions as is.

You'll note near the middle is a commented out line regarding whether you want this to make one list in the directory it acts on or make a separate text file for each movie. Putting a "#" mark at the beginning of a line is referred to as "commenting out" the line. It means it is a comment for humans to read and bash will ignore it. You can make the script work either way by changing which of the pair of lines is commented. One should be commented, and the other not commented.

Comment: What's with the funky variable names?

Comment: De gustibus non est disputandum. They're valid.

Comment: Yes, I've just never seen that form of case used before. If there a particular rationale behind it?

Comment: Yes, some people complain about all upper case. In some RARE instances, it is a valid complaint. But I like my variables to jump out to visual inspection. It makes it easier to read the script for me. So when I think of it, I use camel case like that. I also try to use forms that are valid for bash, dash, and tcsh. Now, don't go dissin' tcsh.

Comment: Hi Lew, I managed to get it to work on some test file, but only once in 5-6 runs... What I do; cd to the folder with files, enter sudo and paste in your code, with all entry above, get the question to enter a directory other than "/", and do so... how am I doing so far?

Comment: Sorry, I should have made that clearer. It goes in a script, not directly into the  command line. I'll edit it. Gimme a minute.

Comment: Thanks Lew, that worked like a charm, very nit script! You made it understandably for a script noob like me.

Comment: You're welcome. I said give me a minute. I always underestimate how long anything is going to take, even after allowing for the fact that  I always underestimate how long anything is going to take. Took an hour. I saved it a little at a time in multiple edits 'cause I figured you might be looking over my shoulder.

Comment: BTW, I'll add a few notes at the end of the answer. If you like it, you can "accept" it by clicking the checkmark symbol beside it.

Comment: It worked fine from my local computer folders, but hitting a speed bump on effort in using the script on my server, any reason for this, do you think?

Comment: Probably permissions on the files or the directory they are in. If you are talking about an internet accessible computer that is meant to be available to other people to see media on, I don't know enough about that to comment on what the permission setup ought to be. But to run the script, whoever is running it would need read, write, and execute perms on the directory the files are in. I don't see any reason the perms on the files themselves would matter as far as running the script goes. If it isn't that, ask somebody who knows about remote access protocols. I don't.

Comment: Solved by running the script form the server, thanks for the added notes, came well in hand.

Comment: @TerjeFolkvord Diffidently and 'umbly tugging at me forlock, may I suggest that if the answer is satisfactory, you might consider clicking the up arrow at the left of my answer to "upvote" it,, or if you REALLY like it, even clicking the checkmark to "accept" it? Thanks.

Comment: Done, thanks for explaining, how to give proper feedback. First time poster here, sorry for not being in tune...